# JPA relational setup for two classes both with composite keys

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Here is my scenario.... I have two tables User Table (which has a composite PK of 3 fields), and OrgFunc Table (which has a composite PK of 2 fields).

I'm trying to configure the @OneToMany relationship in JPA, and I'm not finding a way.

the first class

```java
@Table(name="user")
@IdClass(UserPk.class)
...
public class User implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @column(name="org")
  private String org;

  @Id
  @column(name="user_id")
  private String userId;

  @Id
  @column(name="user_func")
  private String userFunc

  @column=(name = "xyz")
  private String xyz;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  // @MapsId("OrgFuncPk")
  @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="org", referencedColumnName="org"),
        @JoinColumn(name="user_func", referencedColumnName="user_func")
    })
  private List<CliRole> cliRoles;
}
```

the second class

```java
@Table(name="org_func")
@IdClass(OrgFuncPk.class)
...
public class OrgFunc implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @column(name="org")
  private String org;

  @Id
  @column(name="user_func")
  private String userFunc

  @column(name="abc")
  private String abc;
}
```

I'm trying to query the first table with user_id & bring back all the user rows from the two tables combined.

I've tried a lot of variations with no luck, this is the variation the makes most sense to me, but I'm getting the below error at runtime

```
referencedColumnNames(org, user_func) of OrgFunc referencing User not mapped to a single property
```

leaving out the `@JoinColumns` and having a `@MapId("OrgFuncPk")` instead, does let the application run. but throws an error about `ERROR: relation "user_org_fun" does not exists`.

not sure where to go from that point. I think my problem is I'm trying to map a partial composite key from the user to the full composite in the org_func.

Any Ideas?